# Media Element js skipping on server (flash fallback issue)

Tags: javascript, html, flash, element, media

Im using media element js. Works great but one problem when i upload it to a server and test it on IE7 flash fallback mode in internet explorer 9 the video begins to skip as if its playing on fast forawrd. For example its starts jumping 5 to 7 seconds every second.

Anyone know why its doing this and how to fix it.

Heres my code.

thanks in advanced

```
//ON SUCCESSFUL LOAD OF MEDIA ELEMENT
$('audio,video').mediaelementplayer(
{
    //IE7 PRE-REQUISITE
    plugins: ['flash'],
    enableAutosize: true,
    success: function (player, node)
    {
        player.setVideoSize(640, 480);
        //PLAY MOVIE
        player.play();
        //ASSIGN DEFAULT SKIN
        $('#' + node.id + '-mode').html('mode: ' + player.pluginType);
    }
});
```